# ForkJoin and ConcatMap How to get the id and pass it to the other parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to send my reactive formarray in my backend, when i post it, it will automatically generate a unique ID in the backend.my problem is how to get the response id of post1 and pass it to the data type of post1Id? in post2

```
post(){
    this.serv.post1(this.fg.value).pipe(
       concatMap(data =>
        forkJoin([
          this.Post1ID = data.id
          this.serv.post2(this.fg.value?.firstArray),
          this.serv.post3(this.fg.value?.secondArray)
        ])
      )
    ).subscribe({
      next: result => console.log(result),
      error: e => console.log(e)
     })
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *send it to the post2*?

Comment: the post1 id cause i got the fk in post 2. i want the response of id of post1 and put it to the post 2

Comment: I'm guessing you want something like `this.fg.value?.firstArray.map(item => ({ post1Id: data.id, ...item }))`.

Comment: @AndrewAllen yes like that